# Changing IsDevelopment() in IHostingEnvironment in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-core

I'm using ASP.NET Core 2.2 currently. I have 4 environments
**Development** - Developer machine (developing in VS)
and three deployable environments **DevelopmentServer**, **UAT** and **Production**.

I'd like to use **Development** instead of **DevelopmentServer** to be consistent with other applications in my company (they use different technologies) and change **Development** to **Local**.

The final setup would be this:

**Local** - Developer machine (developing in VS)
and three deployable environments:

- **Development**
- **UAT**
- **Production**

My only concern is that there are some helpers methods in `IHostingEnvironment` interface like `IsDevelopment()` which compare the current environment to `"Development"` which in my example would be wrong. It should compare it to `"Local"`. Is there a way to override this behaviour? I can avoid using this method in my code but there may be 3rd party libraries which can potentially rely on this method.

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible to [use the extension method `IsEnvironment`](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/be0a4a7f4cf06cbd6ec714bd1d9afee6bdb040a8/src/Hosting/Abstractions/src/HostingEnvironmentExtensions.cs#L65)

```
if (env.IsEnvironment("Local"))
{
    // your environment specific code
}
```

> `env` is [IHostingEnvironment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.ihostingenvironment?view=aspnetcore-2.2) in this case

Comment: okay but what if there is a 3rd party library that calls IsDevelopment()? I know how to check what environment I am in. I want to avoid confusion for 3rd party tools or .net core classes which are using IsDevelopment() method

Comment: I think if you have no option to control the classes `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.EnvironmentName` or `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.HostingEnvironmentExtensions` for your 3rd party library, you are out of luck.